The YouTube embed URL is not working on Chrome and Edge but works in Firefox. Similarly, the embedded Vimeo URL works fine in all three browsers
I have an application that helps create interactive videos. After creating the videos, we generate an embed URL within an iframe. The problem is that for YouTube URLs, it doesn't work on Chrome and Edge browsers but works fine on Firefox. However, when I tried a Vimeo URL, the embed URL worked on Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. How can I resolve this issue?
Here is the embed urls of Chrome and Vimeo
Chrome:
        <div>
            <iframe style="width:1000px; height:600px;border:none;" 
                    src="https://test.letmetourit.us/embedscenemedia?Id=uKPAbISmExd7g5O06p9XaA%3D%3D" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
                    allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
        </div>

Here is the url for Vimeo:
        <div>
            <iframe style="width:1000px; height:600px;border:none;" src="https://test.letmetourit.us/embedscenemedia?Id=KrEj6ZlqlxcTbRkH%2FTu6VQ%3D%3D" 
                    allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
        </div>

Is there anything I have missed configuring to make it work in Chrome and Edge?
i have tried adding these settings in the Web.Config
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' x-content-type-options nosniff; 
             script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com https://test.letmetourit.us;
             frame-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com https://test.letmetourit.us;"/>
      </customHeaders>

but its still not working.

Any CSP related errors in the browsers?

@HalvorSakshaug no
